# Linqpad: LINQPad.Util.Cache throws error if query file is modified, saved and re-run. "Cannot load type" error

Tags: linqpad

Using the amazing [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) with a C# script. Get an error using the `Util.Cache` storing a custom class declared in the same script. How to resolve, other than restarting LinqPad please?

##### Reproduce error:

1. Add any char to the comment
2. save file
3. run again

##### Error raised:

```
Cannot load type 'UserQuery+IPerson' from cache.
Data    
(0 items)
HelpLink    null
HResult -2146233088
InnerException  null
Message Cannot load type 'UserQuery+IPerson' from cache.
Source  LINQPad.Runtime
StackTrace     at LINQPad.Util.Cache[T](Func`1 dataFetcher, String key, Boolean& fromCache)
   at LINQPad.Util.Cache[T](Func`1 dataFetcher, String key)
   at UserQuery.Main(), line 3
TargetSite  
RuntimeMethodInfo•••
CacheConverter.CanConvert (Type sourceType, Type targetType, HashSet<TypeType> visitedTypes)
```

##### Linqpad query code

Here is the code being run:

```
void Main()
{
   IPerson p = Util.Cache<IPerson>(()=>new Person("Bob"), "person_bob9");
   p.Dump();
   // add any char after here, save re-run, error thrown: a
}

interface IPerson{string Name {get;init;}}
class Person:IPerson
{
   public Person(string name)=> Name = name;
   public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

##### Notes

Maybe this happens because the Person class is compiled by linqpad into a dll each time the file is modified and run. When an instance of Person is stored in a cache, this might differ from the current Person type declaration, hence the error.

Comment: This belongs in a bug report on the Linqpad site. Not here.

Comment: Perhaps, not sure if it is a bug or something else.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it works with functions

```
void Main()
{
    var p = Util.Cache<Person>(() => AddPerson("uuuu"), "cached_user").Dump();
    p.Dump();
    string s = "";

}

interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; init; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public Person(string name) => Name = name;
    public string Name { get; init; }
}

public Person AddPerson(string Name)
{
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return new Person(Name);
}
```

Comment: It's the [serializable] attribute placed onto the Person class which solves the caching problem.. Joe wrote to me on the LinqPad forum. Thanks for the help